# TomEE says started but it isn't

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu, apache-tomee

When I try to start Apache TomEE plus 1.7.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 x64 via bin/startup.sh i get the output:

```
:~/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/bin# ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/
Using CLASSPATH:       /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/bin/bootstrap.jar:/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

But it seems not to fully start. It is not available via ip:8080 from remote

```
netstat -a | grep 8080
```

returns nothing

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat
```

returns

```
root      1176     1  5 07:48 pts/0    00:00:10 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -javaagent:/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/lib/openejb-javaagent.jar -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/endorsed -classpath /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/bin/bootstrap.jar:/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2 -Dcatalina.home=/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root      1232  1144  0 07:51 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
```

/logs/catalina.out:

```
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.62 (1.7.2)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 7 2015 17:14:55 UTC
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.62.0
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            3.13.0-71-generic
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_91-b02
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/conf/logging.properties
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -javaagent:/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/lib/openejb-javaagent.jar
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/endorsed
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/temp
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:29 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:29 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: ********************************************************************************
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Startup: Sat Jan 16 07:48:31 EST 2016
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Copyright 1999-2013 (C) Apache OpenEJB Project, All Rights Reserved.
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Version: 4.7.2
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Build date: 20150517
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Build time: 10:10
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: ********************************************************************************
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: openejb.home = /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: openejb.base = /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initializeOWB
INFO: Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@703601d7
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initializeOWB
INFO: Succeeded in installing singleton service
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:31 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory init
INFO: openejb configuration file is '/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/conf/tomee.xml'
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:32 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:32 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:32 AM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.system.apps=true'
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:32 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: openejb
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:33 AM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Using openejb.deploymentId.format '{ejbName}'
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:33 AM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Auto-deploying ejb openejb/Deployer: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:33 AM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Auto-deploying ejb openejb/ConfigurationInfo: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:33 AM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Auto-deploying ejb MEJB: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=MEJB)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:33 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=Default Stateless Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateless Container)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:33 AM org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig createContainer
INFO: Auto-creating a container for bean openejb/Deployer: Container(type=STATELESS, id=Default Stateless Container)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:33 AM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFO: Enterprise application "openejb" loaded.
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:33 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:33 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:33 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Container(id=Default Stateless Container)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:33 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createAppClassLoader
INFO: Not creating another application classloader for openejb
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:33 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Assembling app: openejb
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.jndiname.format={deploymentId}{interfaceType.openejbLegacyName}'
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=openejb/DeployerBusinessRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/Deployer!org.apache.openejb.assembler.Deployer) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/Deployer) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=openejb/ConfigurationInfoBusinessRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/ConfigurationInfo!org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.cmd.ConfigurationInfo) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/ConfigurationInfo) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=MEJB) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/MEJB!javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/MEJB) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Stateless Container)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB, ejb-name=MEJB, container=Default Stateless Container)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, ejb-name=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, container=Default Stateless Container)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Started Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Stateless Container)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Started Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB, ejb-name=MEJB, container=Default Stateless Container)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Started Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, ejb-name=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, container=Default Stateless Container)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler deployMBean
INFO: Deployed MBean(openejb.user.mbeans:application=openejb,group=org.apache.openejb.assembler.monitoring,name=JMXDeployer)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:34 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Deployed Application(path=openejb)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager initServer
INFO: Creating ServerService(id=cxf)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager initServer
INFO: Creating ServerService(id=cxf-rs)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO:   ** Bound Services **
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager printRow
INFO:   NAME                 IP              PORT
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO: -------
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO: Ready!
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 8327 ms
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener bindResource
INFO: Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'UserDatabase' of type 'org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase'.
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Resource(id=UserDatabase)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.62 (1.7.2)
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/webapps/host-manager
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFO: ------------------------- localhost -> /host-manager
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/webapps/host-manager
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFO: Enterprise application "/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/webapps/host-manager" loaded.
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Assembling app: /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/webapps/host-manager
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:35 AM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initSingleton
INFO: Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@703601d7
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:36 AM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:36 AM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:36 AM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:36 AM org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer validateInjectionPoints
INFO: All injection points were validated successfully.
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:36 AM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 225 ms.
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:36 AM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder deployWebApps
INFO: using context file /root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml
Jan 16, 2016 7:48:36 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Deployed Application(path=/root/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/webapps/host-manager)
```

no "Server startup in X ms"

ufw status:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8005                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8009                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8005 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8009 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Any ideas why it won't start?

Answer (score 0):

If someone else has the same problem: I found a solution:

```
apt-get install haveged
```

worked for me